# Roles for uploading layers in geoexplorer

Tags: geoexplorer

What kind of users I have to create for uploading layers? I tried with users that are not admins and they have specific role with write access on workspace, but it works only once or twice. What I need is following: many "public" users with anonymous login and access to public workspace (stores and layers) and several power users which can see all in public workspace but they have their common private workspace for writing. Private workspace is for uploading their shapefiles and geotifs, and that workspace first users don't see. So, is it possible to have non-admin users for that feature in geoexplorer?
OS is Windows 2008 Server, I don't know is it necessary to give some permissions on tmp\upload and private folders?